# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from - not related to known User Agent bug; curl, wget and file_get_contents work

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I've found a lot of similar questions in StackOverflow, but none of them solved my issue.

The following code throws an exception:

```
$soap_options = array(
            'trace' => TRUE,
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
            'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36'
        );

        $wsdlUrl = 'https://www.iatspayments.com/NetGate/CustomerLink.asmx?WSDL';

        $soap = new \SoapClient($wsdlUrl, $soap_options);
```

The exception is:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://www.iatspayments.com/NetGate/CustomerLink.asmx?WSDL' : failed to load external entity "https://www.iatspayments.com/NetGate/CustomerLink.asmx?WSDL"
```

I can `file_get_contents` from the same PHP file with no  errors thrown.

Any of the following also works from CLI:

```
curl -A '' -4 url
curl -A '' -6 url
curl -A 'PHP' -4 url
curl -A 'PHP' -6 url
```

Have really no idea what's going on. Please help to isolate and identify the issue.